# I have a whole bunch of bookmars in TXT file with the corresponding format, taked from google chrome browser, can i turn it back into bookmarks?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, backup, browser, bookmarks

Some time ago - i lost a lot of bookmarks, and problem is, they are split into different bookmarks backups files in chrome. Well, i tooked all of missing bookmarks from all files and put them in one, and tried to provide it for chrome. It didn't worked. Google rewriting it all only to current state of bookmarks, where most of them are lost.
Is there a way to do somethings with these, except just use links to create all new bookmarks ?
Now, they have format like "

```
        "date_added": "13263638786903702",
        "guid": "9ded16fd-46a4-443f-aef0-76f0712f3486",
        "id": "4",
        "name": "YouTube",
        "type": "url",
        "url": "https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions"
     }, {
        "date_added": "13185197147729846",
        "guid": "5ad0cc12-13e1-4364-9c4f-41cbec768a60",
        "id": "6",
        "meta_info": {
           "last_visited_desktop": "13249601344493526"
        },
        "name": "Likes",
        "type": "url",
        "url": "https://coub.com/likes"
     }, {
        "date_added": "13252570776888080",
        "guid": "fecc6140-2b41-4ea4-9603-018b826be9db",
        "id": "7",
        "name": "Mail.ru",
        "type": "url",
        "url": "https://mail.ru/"
     },
```

and else. So, as i think, it's format for google chrome bookmarks exactly, right ?
Problem is - it's didn't accept all my bookmarks from different backups files mashed together. Any solutions to make this work ? I have them all in that state.

Actually, if there's not a single way to make it work, i can just use links and create all new bookmarks in firefox and export them or something. Only problem then - how to use all existing custom names to bookmarks, instead of default ones.

So there's basically two questions. If you can't help me with first one, at least, try on second. I would be glad to receive any help with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This text is a JSON format, although your text fragment seems a bit truncated.

You could try to use the extension
[JSON Bookmarks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-bookmarks/nhcplcjcgpjimjnohoijcjglolbdhahg?hl=en)
which does:

> Update a local bookmarks directory directly from a JSON source.
>
> With this extension, bookmarks from a central JSON source can be loaded / synced into a local bookmark directory.

If this doesn't work, find your `Bookmarks` file,
situated on Windows at
`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\PROFILE\Bookmarks`,
using your USERNAME and PROFILE (perhaps "Default").
Backup the file first. See
[Where Are Google Chrome Bookmarks Stored](https://www.alphr.com/where-are-google-chrome-bookmarks-stored/).

Close Chrome and use a text editor to insert your bookmarks into the file,
while respecting its syntax and ensuring that all parenthesis are
well-balanced.

If done correctly, your bookmarks should now be available.

Comment: I Tried to do as you described "insert your bookmarks into the file, while respecting its syntax and ensuring that all parenthesis are well-balanced."
But as soon i open google - all bookmarks was reinstalled as old ones, and bookmarks file (with new ones) were renamed as bookmarks (with .bak extension), so somehow google updating bookmarks only to current state, even tho there is no file to do so.
Also, all files with bookmarks described as just "file", it doesn't have any extensions, and could be opened with just notepad, if they were .json, i would import them long ago.

Comment: My mistake - I specified the bookmarks file for Microsoft Edge, not Chrome. I fixed my answer.

Comment: Well, i tried it anyway, before looking for answer in that site, but that didn't worked anyway. So, as i had all my bookmarks with url stored in file, with notepad++ i cut only URL's, used service to open all URL in new tabs inside Firefox browser, and saved them all in one click, as bookmarks, then, simply imported them with google chrome. Actually, i inverted queue they had, because somewhy firefox turning all next tabs in left side, instead of right, as it doing google, so in bookmarks, they would have inverted queue. Anyway, it's done, but thanks for answering, your words gave me idea.